# trying to do a jquery pass value using select tag not request form action to modal in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm new in `laravel` and trying to do something like passing a value to a modal form with the form action just select tag. my question is how do I store a Jquery value to this `PHP laravel` variable here is my code.

**page1.blade.php**

```
<select id="selectUser" name="selectUser" class="form-control text-md-right">
 <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select Service</option>
    @foreach($ListServices as $lst)
       <option value="{{$lst->ServiceName}}">{{ $lst->ServiceName }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<br /><br />
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#searchprofile">
 SEARCH
</a>
@include('searchview-modal')


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#selectUser').on('change', function() {
        var search = this.value;    <-- this how?
        {{ $lst->ServiceName = "this.value" }}
    });
});
```

**My Modal Form which I include search view-modal.blade.php**

```
<!-- MODAL FORM -->
<div class="modal fade" id="searchprofileservices" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="searchprofileservicesLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        @if(isset($lst->ServiceName))
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="searchprofileservicesLabel">SEARCH RESULT {{ $lst->ServiceName }}</h5>
        @else
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="searchprofileservicesLabel">SEARCH RESULT </h5>
        @endif
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th>IMAGE</th>
                    <th>NAME</th>
                    <th>RATE</th>
                    <th>##</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($ProfileList as $Profile)

                    @if($Profile->name == $lst->ServiceName)

                        // add to column...

                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>

        </div> <!-- End of modal-body -->
        </div> <!-- End of modal-content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question**

if there may be another way for this implement in laravel please do let me know that I may learn some about the framework like I said I'm new with it and trying to explore its capability.

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong way you are trying. Please do it as follows

- First of all you have to make a request to the controller with the selected user.
- Then perform a query and retrieve a collection according to selected user.
- then loop it on modal body.
  You can do it via Jquery ajax method.

Comment: thank you for the answer sir can you do a video for it and try to link it here sir i'm more on visual learner not more on theory but i understand your teaching i just can vision it yet which i need and i'm still in a learning stage on this language framework